# Can we detect malicious redirections by retrieving the webpage's headers?

Tags: http, url-redirection

Is it possible to know if there are `URL` redirections (to malicious websites) by retrieving the   `HTTP` request and response `headers` of the legitimate website   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection can be performed in various other ways (like JavaScript) which will not involve sending any headers. So no, headers are not a reliable source.